# Linq count number of differences in lists in a collection

Tags: c#, linq

I want to count the number of differences (or similarities) in lists within a collection.The following code is a for loop which produces the right results, comparing every other record with the first record.
Is there a way to do it better? With Linq, perhaps?

```
public void Main(){
        _records = new ObservableCollection<Record>();
        _records.Add(new Record { Name = "Correct", Results = new List<string> { "A", "B","C" } , Score="100%"} );
        _records.Add(new Record { Name = "John", Results = new List<string> { "A", "B" ,"C" } } ); //Expect score to be 3/3  (100%)
        _records.Add(new Record { Name = "Joseph", Results = new List<string> { "A", "C","B" } }); //Expect score to be 2/3 (67%)
        _records.Add(new Record { Name = "James", Results = new List<string> { "C", "C", "C" } }); //Expect score to be 1/3 (33%)

        for(int i = 1; i < _records.Count(); i++) // Each Results in the _records except "Correct"
        {
            float score = _records[0].Results.Count();
            _records[i].Score = string.Format("{0:p1}", (score - CountDifferences(_records[i].Results, _records[0].Results) )  / score );
        }


}

private int CountDifferences(List<string> x, List<string> y)
{
    return (x.Zip(y, (a, b) => a.Equals(b) ? 0 : 1).Sum());
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect the score of the 3rd record to be 67%?

Comment: I can only assume you really meant Joseph was getting 33% score; as hinted at by Enigmativity. Because the only grade that lines up by index is the A. Based on that assumption I gave an answer that uses Dictionarys instead of your custom class.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made the LINQ (with lambda expressions) statement work off a dictionary that uses the students' name as the key and custom class Record as the value. Then compare that against a separate List the grades are expected to be.

```
List<string> expected = new List<string>(){"A", "B","C" };
Dictionary<string, Record> _records = new Dictionary<string, Record>();
_records["John"] = new Record { Name = "John", Results = new List<string> { "A", "B" ,"C" } } ;
_records["Joseph"]= new Record { Name = "Joseph", Results = new List<string> { "A", "C","B" } } ;
_records["James"] = new Record { Name = "James", Results = new List<string> { "C", "C", "C" } } ;

foreach(var v in _records){
    decimal count = v.Value.Results.Where((x,index) => expected[index]==x).Count()/(decimal)expected.Count();
    v.Value.Score = String.Format("{0:P0}",count);
}

foreach(var v in _records)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}",v.Value.Name,v.Value.Score);
```

Comment: Thanks for that indexing function!

Comment: @waterling I wonder why this has a down-vote. Besides selecting an answer you may also up-vote answers and comments that add value or help you in understanding something. This can be in your own question or any solutions you find in searching for answers to problems you have. Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't implying you did. I was just asking if you could upvote it as well to having selected it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about doing it like this:

```
var results =
    from r0 in _records.Take(1)
    from r in _records
    let score = (double)r0.Results.Count()
    let differences = CountDifferences(r.Results, r0.Results)
    select new { record = r, score = ((score - differences) / score).ToString("p1") };

foreach (var result in results)
{
    result.record.Score = result.score;
}
```

I would, hovever suggest that you do not have `.Score` as a property of `Record` as a score is only valid when you can compare one record against another. That would mean that if you have three separate results the score could be different if you compare against either of the other two.

So I would suggest this:

```
public class Record
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Results;
    public double GetScore(Record benchmark)
    {
        var max = benchmark.Results.Count;
        var differences = benchmark.Results
            .Zip(this.Results, (a, b) => a == b)
            .Where(r => r == false)
            .Count();
        return ((double)max - differences) / max;
    }
}
```

Then just do this query to get the results:

```
var results =
    from r0 in _records.Take(1)
    from r in _records
    select new
    {
        record = r,
        score = r.GetScore(r0).ToString("p1")
    };
```

That gives me:

[image: results]